# SHA -1 algorithm source code

Tags: sha1

SHA 1 algorithm will compress and convert the input data into 160 bit format.so, i need java source code for this SHA 1 alogorithm in which whatever the input data we give,that needs to be converted into 160 bit format.please help to solve this

Comment: I redirect you to the guidelines of StackOverflow about asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: but i need program for SHA -1 algorithm,is it not right to ask for that.i didn't understand what you have said

Comment: Do you want to to implement it ?

Comment: yes.i need to write java source code,which performs the operation of  SHA-1 algorithm

Comment: i will give string as input then it should be converted into 160 bit format(compresssed)

Comment: Please show what you have tried for now.

Comment: Then research about by yourself before coming here. There is great explanation on Wikipedia. If you want more informations, it is defined in [RFC 3174](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3174).